# Making the next call to strtok(NULL,) repeat the current one

Tags: strtok

Is there a way to make the next call to `strtok()` repeat the current return?

To in a sense PUSH it back onto the `strtok(NULL,)` stack?

I'm in recursion, down through several levels of long switch cases, where a special-case that makes me need to do extra things before *now*, so I do them and then recurse. The problem is I need to PUSH the current return from `strtok(NULL,"delim")` back *on the stack* so that the recursion gets it again when the recursion calls `strtok(NULL,"delim")`

I could program around this but its not as simple or as readable as if I could un-strtok() once.

Here is a simple example of what I mean. *un-strtok()*

```
/* UN-strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char tok[] =" ,.-";
  char * pch;
  int i=0;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,tok);
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    if (i==1) {
      //un_strtok(NULL,tok);
    }
    i++;
    pch = strtok (NULL, tok);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It will return this:

```
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
sample
string
-Done-
```

If the un_strtok() worked it would give:

```
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
a
sample
string
-Done-
```

Comment: Well I have a working solution, but as I have only written two answers and they got 0 votes I'm no longer allowed to write answers. When I can answer questions again I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you write your own `strtok`, its pretty easy to do.  Here's a common way of implementing `strtok`:

```
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **save) {
    if (!str) str = *save;
    char *rv = str + strspn(str, delim);
    if (*rv) {
        str = rv + strcspn(rv, delim);
        if (*str) *str++ = 0;
        *save = str;
        return rv; }
    return 0; }

static char *strtok_save;
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim) {
    return strtok_r(str, delim, &strtok_save); }
```

With the above, you can write unstrtok as:

```
void unstrtok_r(char *tok, char *delim, char **save) {
    if (*save) *--save = *delim;
    *save = tok; }
void unstrtok(char *tok, char *delim) {
    unstrtok_r(tok, delim, &strtok_save); }
```

The above requires calling `unstrtok` with precisely the last token returned by `strtok`, and you can only `unstrtok` a single token.

Comment: Offtopic: that is a very different brace style

Comment: @vidit: Not that different -- it's "indent" brace style -- indentation shows the structure and the braces are just there (tacked on to the end of the lines) to make the compiler understand it.  The human reader can just ignore the braces.

Comment: Seems like you love Python :)